# Why do Shapley values increase over time?

Tags: forecasting, boosting, marginal-effect, shapley-value

I calculated the Shapley values (using xgboot package, gbm regression model) of several big actors in the cocoa market and received results which I cannot explain: it seems that Shapley increases (the trend, in general) for all of them. The same thing happened when I calculate it for other sectors. Does it make sense? If it does, what stands behind these results? If not, what could be my mistake?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Here is the code, in general, although the question is more about the meaning of the results:

```
library(SHAPforxgboost)
library(tidyverse)
library(xgboost) #shapley for boosting method


X <- data.matrix(df[,-1]) #all regions (x)

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = X, label = df[[1]]) 
  
  fit <- xgb.train( #train the gbm model
    params = list(
      objective = "reg:squarederror", 
      learning_rate = 0.1
    ), 
    data = dtrain,
    nrounds = 100,
    eval_metric = "rmse"
  )
    
  shap <- shap.prep(xgb_model = fit, X_train = X)
```

[image]

Comment: We miss some information here but on face values, yes, this makes sense. Assuming that these are not inflation adjusted cocoa prices, prices do raise throughout the years. In addition, even if we assume inflation adjustment the appetite for cocoa has grown *and* cocoa producers are more likely to get some less unfair rewards that before (so again the price goes up). Side-note: I would avoid loading `tidyverse` and just load only the packages needed. Less likely for conflicts as well as more readily available code to package.